# malloc() and free() in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program in C language and I used malloc() in a function. Do I have to use free() after in the function? Will it cause a memory leak if I don't free it since it is just a function?

Thank you.

```
void insertFirst(int key, int data) {
   //create a link
   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
   link->key = key;
   link->data = data;
    
   //point it to old first node
   link->next = head;
    
   //point first to new first node
   head = link;
}
```

Comment: You've added it to a linked list so you should not free it. Whoever later removes it from the linked list should free it, as needed.

Comment: You need to free it when you don't need it anymore. That is, when deleting the node, or cleaning up the whole list.

Comment: @jarmod unless the one who later removes it from the list keeps a reference and keeps on using it

Comment: @gkhaos hence "as needed", but yes.

Comment: yes it will cause a memory leak if you don't free it . Because malloc allocates memory on the heap , rather than the stack. But it's up to you to decide when to free it. Like @jarmod said , this is a linked list , so if you free it  right after the function , you won't be able to access it . I suggest you implement a free_list function that will free every node of your list that you will be able to call when you want.

Comment: A memory leak occurs in general, when you allocate some memory and *lose* the pointer to it, so it cannot be freed anymore. In case you are still keeping track of it (that is, it is in your linked list), no memory is "leaked".

Comment: @AmineBensalem: I wouldn't complicate it with implementation-specific details like heap or stack. `malloc()` provisions allocated memory, which is only freed if done explicitly.

Comment: For further details have a look at [Storage Duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). Memory allocated with malloc has dynamic storage duration (often called heap memory). On the other hand are variables like `struct node *link` which has automatic storage duration (don't be confused tho... the pointer has automatic, but the memory it is pointing to has dynamic storage duration)

Comment: The intent of the code is to add a node to a dynamic linked list.  The free() function would be used in the routine that removes a node from the linked list, not when the node is added.  The malloc() and free() functions need to be used as a matched set to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function adds a node that was dynamically allocated within the function to a singly-linked list.

Within the function you shall not free the allocated memory for the node. Otherwise the list will refer to an invalid object.

You need to write a function that will free all the allocated memory (nodes) for the list when the list is not needed any more.

For example the function can look the following way (taking into account that the pointer `head` is declared as a global variable in your implementation of the list)

```
void clear( void )
{
    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your program allocates memory, it remains allocated until your program frees it.

Generally, you are not required to free memory. In general-purpose multi-user operating systems, the operating system releases all resources your program held when the program exits. However, it is generally good practice to release memory when your program is done using it. This is particularly so in programs that do various things repetitively. If, in each repetition, a program allocated memory and did not free it, then the program’s use of memory would grow and grow over time. That can interfere with other programs running on the system.

In simple student programs, you will not observe any bad effects from failing to free a little memory, other than tools that diagnose memory leaks complaining. However, it is a good practice you must learn for writing practical programs later.

Generally, functions that allocate memory are paired with functions that release memory. At the lowest level, `malloc` allocates memory and `free` releases it. Then, in your function to add a node to a linked list, `insertFirst` would allocate memory using `malloc` and would not release it, because the memory is needed to hold the object in a linked list. Rather, `insertFirst` would be paired with some function that removes a node from the linked list, and that function would call `free` to release the memory.